# Is there any other way to verify cpu on a remote machine besides snmp?

Tags: nagios, snmp, plugin

I am writing a script for Nagios that would be able to verify the cpu load on a remote machine

I have already this line

```
snmpget 127.0.0.1 -v 2c -c public .1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.11.9.0 | grep -Eo '[0-9]+$'
```

but, apparently, I cannot read this info if the remote machine does not have snmpd preinstalled and all mibs.

Therefore I wonder if there is another way to monitor cpu on a distant machine? I was thinking about

```
 top
```

But where is the information that informs me about cpu?

Comment: see this answer: https://serverfault.com/a/73459

Comment: Thank you, it's just I need to write my own plugin not to use the precast ones.